# How to install global MIUI/google services on a Redmi Note 8 Pro?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, xiaomi, miui, redmi

I have recently bought a Redmi 8 Pro in China with the Chinese MIUI 10. Because I live in the UK, I would like to use google services and apps such as Whatsapp and Facebook that are not available on the official Xiaomi app store.

So far there is no global MIUI available on the [official website](https://en.miui.com) and Redmi 8 Pro is only expected to be released in India in [Oct](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/redmi-note-8-pro-india-launch-eight-weeks-away-xiaomi-india-chief-manu-kumar-jain-confirms-2092527). Does it mean that there will be no global MIUI available until then? Since Redmi 8 Pro uses MTK chips, there is [rumour (in Chinese)](https://www.zhihu.com/question/50231539/answer/146271197) that no global MIUI is ever going to be available for this phone.

Can I ask if there is any way for me to use this phone conveniently in the UK, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You an try flashing gapps (provides Google apps and services framework) in your device and see if it works. This would require unlocking bootloader and flashing TWRP recovery which "may" void your warranty.